# How to get telegram message in mobile device when session termination in telethon?

Tags: python, web-scraping, telethon

I try to get data from telegram using telethon
I'm using the below code

```
date_of_post = datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 19)

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat , offset_date = date_of_post):
        print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

But if the session is terminated I can't get the data